If $A$ has strictly positive reach, does the set $\{ x \in A \colon B(x,\epsilon) \subseteq A \}$ also?
Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ with $\text{reach}(A) > 0$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reach_(mathematics) ).
Define for any $\epsilon>0$, the "removal of $\epsilon$-thick boundary",
$$
A^{-\epsilon} = \{ x \in A \colon B(x,\epsilon) \subseteq A \}.
$$
The question is: Does $A^{-\epsilon}$ again have strictly positive reach?

Note that if one replaces 'strictly positive reach' with 'convex', then the assertion is true.
I know that in general strictly positive reach is not closed under intersections.
However, I have tried to come up with counterexamples but with no luck. This has then led me to believe the answer might be yes since maybe one can use the point in $A^{-\epsilon}$
which is closest to $\partial A$. However, then this would mean that the reach would increase for $A^{-\epsilon}$, which I am a bit skeptical of...
Asking ChatGPT4 didn't provide additional insight either.

Following Federer's Curvature measures (p. 419):
Definition. The reach of a subset $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is the largest $\epsilon \in [0, +\infty]$ such that if $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathrm{dist}(x, A) < \epsilon$, then there exists a unique $p \in A$ such that $\mathrm{dist}(x, A) = \mathrm{dist}(x, p)$.
Remark. It is not complicated to prove that a set $A$ of positive reach is necessarily closed, in which case $A^{-\epsilon}$ is also closed.
In dimension $n=2$, I have found counter-examples of sets $A$ of positive reach such that $A^{-\epsilon}$ has zero reach. (These examples generalize to higher dimensions.) The constructions are based on two facts:

Smooth curves have positive reach (given by the minimal radius of curvature of the curve);
The operations $A \mapsto A^{\epsilon}$ and $A \mapsto A^{-\epsilon}$ are neither left nor right inverses to each other.

Roughly speaking, this allows to construct $A$ as a smoothen version of $A' := X^{\epsilon}$ where $X$ has zero reach and $X = A^{-\epsilon}$.
The case when $X$ (hence $A$) is unbounded appears to be simpler (and allows for connected $X$ and $A$). When $X$ (hence $A$) is bounded, I only know examples with disconnected $X$ (but $A$ can still be connected). It'd be interesting to see if $X$ could be chosen to be connected too (the difficulty here is that since $X^{\epsilon} \subsetneq A$, we may quite well have $X \subsetneq A^{-\epsilon}$ with the latter of positive reach).

Unbounded counter-example. We consider dimension $n=2$. I'll produce a disconnected example; easy variations on the construction yield examples where both $A$ and $A^{-\epsilon}$ are connected.
Let's consider $X \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ to be the 'thin broken ladder' (broken at the middle of each step)
$$X = \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}_{\ge 3}}([-\infty, -1/k] \cup [1/k,\infty]) \times \{ k \} .$$
Note that $X$ has zero reach, because each point $x_k = (0, k) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus X$ satisfies $$1/k = \mathrm{dist}(x_k, X) = \mathrm{dist}(x_k, p_k)=\mathrm{dist}(x_k, q_k)$$ where $p_k = (-1/k, k)$ and $q_k = (1/k, k)$.
Let $\epsilon = 1/3$ and set $Y = \overline{X^{\epsilon}}$. $Y$ has zero reach, precisely because the balls $\bar{B}(p_k, \epsilon)$ and $\bar{B}(q_k, \epsilon)$ overlap in a way which produces two 'concave wedges' above and below $x_k$. Moreover, $X = Y^{-\epsilon}$.
Consider also the 'thick ladder' $Z = \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}_{\ge 3}} \mathbb{R} \times [k - 1/3, k+1/3]$. $Z$ has reach $1/6$ (half the distance between consecutive 'steps'). Note that $Y \subset Z$; in fact, $Z$ is essentially the union of the convex hulls of each 'step' in the 'ladder' $Y$.
Without going here over all the painstaking details (see the next case for a bit more of information), we pick $A$ to satisfy $Y \subset A \subset Z$; it is a 'smoothing' of $Y$ in such a way that $\partial A$ is an union of smooth curves, all of which having everywhere very small curvature (say curvature $< 1/10^{23}$). Hence $\partial A$ is a small deformation of $\partial Z$; as such, the reach of $A$ is only slightly less than $1/6$. As we can arrange to have $\partial A \cap \partial Z = \partial Y \cap \partial Z$, we have $A^{-\epsilon} = Y^{-\epsilon} = X$.
Bounded counter-example. Again $n=2$. Consider $X = \{0\} \cup \{x_k = 1/k : k \in \mathbb{N}_{\ge 1}\}$ and consider $\epsilon = 1$. Set $A' = \overline{X^{\epsilon}} = \bar{B}(0, 1) \cup \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}_{\ge 1}} \bar{B}(x_k, 1)$. Our goal is to 'smoothen' the boundary of $\partial A'$; by symmetry under reflection $(x,y) \mapsto (x,-y)$, let's focus on the boundary part $\partial A'_- \subset \partial A'$ with $y \le 0$.
The boundary $\partial A'_-$ is a union of circle arcs (of radius of curvature $1$). For $k \in \mathbb{N}_{\ge 1}$, definite $y_k := (x_k + x_{k+1})/2$. (For convenience, set $y_0 = 2$.) it is easily seen that the part of $\partial A'_-$ with coordinate $x \in [y_{k}, y_{k-1}]$ is an arc inside $\partial B(x_k, 1)$. Therefore, $\partial A'_-$ is, for $0 \le x \le 1$, the graph of the function $\alpha$ given by
$$\mbox{for $x \in [y_{k}, y_{k-1}] \cap [0,1]$, } \; \alpha(x) = - \sqrt{1 - (x-x_k)^2}.$$
Hence the points where $\partial A'_-$ has 'zero radius of curvature' are the those with $x = x_k$.
Also consider $Y = [0,1]$ and $Z = \overline{Y^{\epsilon}} = \bar{B}(0,1) \cup ([0,1] \times [-1,1]) \cup \bar{B}(1,1)$. We certainly have $A \subsetneq Z$ and $Z$ has infinite reach. Note that $\partial Z_-$ is the union of two quarter of circles and of the line $[0,1] \times \{-1\}$. Therefore, $\partial Z_-$ is, for $0 \le x \le 1$, the graph of the function $\zeta(x) = -1$.
We aim to smoothen $\partial A'$ over the interval $x \in [0,1]$ in such a way that the region $A$ delimited by (i.e., whose boundary is) the smoothened $\partial A'$ will satisfy $A' \subsetneq A \subsetneq Z$. The smoothening needs to be done in such a way that $A$ will still have $A^{-\epsilon} = X$; this is guaranteed if, for each $x \in [0,1]$, the set $(\{x\} \times [-1,1]) \cap A$ has length $< 2$ iff $x \not \in X$. To do all this, it suffices that $\partial A_-$ be given, for $0 \le x \le 1$, as the graph of a ($C^2$-)smooth function $\gamma(x)$ which satisfies $\zeta(x) \le \gamma(x) \le \alpha(x)$ with equality (on either side) iff $x \in X$.
The existence of such a function $\gamma$ is a standard exercise. For instance, fix some ($C^2$-)smooth function $\chi : \mathbb{R} \to [0, 1]$ with $\chi(u) > 0$ iff $u \in (0,1)$. Then pick for $x \in \mathbb{R}$
$$ \gamma(x) = -1 + \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}_{k \ge 1}} a_k \chi((x-y_{k+1})/(y_k - y_{k+1}))$$
where the scalars $a_k > 0$ decrease with $k$ rapidly enough for $\gamma$ to be ($C^2$-)smooth (using e.g. Theorem 7.17 in 'Baby Rudin') and to have $\gamma \le \alpha$ for $x \in [0,1]$. By choosing $\gamma$ arbitrarily close to $\zeta$ (i.e., the $a_k$s arbitrarily small), the reach of $A$ can be made arbitrarily large.
